# How to stop a node program while in another command window

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-server

I have an ubuntu server running with 2 node websites on it and I keep closing the terminals that start the app so I cannot shut the app down to make changes, I end up restarting the server.

How can I see what node instances are running and then stop them, or how do I stop a node instance through programming and I'll just make a button that kills the node instance. Either way...

Comment: In production you should use some process manager like https://github.com/foreverjs/forever or https://github.com/Unitech/pm2 both give you list of running processes and a allows you to start, stop and restart any of your apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use PM2 or systemd you can get the list of all the node.js instances running using

```
ps -aux | grep node
```

once you have the list of all nodejs processes you can kill any process using `kill` command

```
kill "Process ID goes here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a process manager. [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) is the most widely recommended.

`npm install pm2@latest -g`

then

`pm2 start app.js`

Alternatively you can use something like [screen](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server) to have multiple terminal sessions running in one window